# HTML + CSS DIV alignment layout

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to make a portfolio site, but I just can't figure out the CSS part in combination with the DIV's. I am trying to make a site with this layout:

[image: Hand-drawn picture of layout design]

And this is what I've got:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 380px;
  background-color: #5B91AC;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.menu img {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.content {
  max-width: 768px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Start of menu (at left side) -->
  <div class="menu">
    <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/788x208" />
  </div>
  <!-- End of menu -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gv19a3mw/1/

Could someone point me in the right direction or help me with my CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve what you want [Demo Pen](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/xbyPYm)

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu{
  height:100vh;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #5B91AC;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.menu img {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 25%;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  /* max-width:768px */;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;    
}
```

Comment: @JanvanDijk You can accept the answer so it'll help others!